# Kubernetes Custom Autoscaler Prometheus Adapter Scaling Up Incorrectly

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-hpa

We are using prometheus adapter to allow for custom metric auto scaling in k8s. We have everything setup where the HPA is getting the metric but it is exhibiting improper scale up even when the metric is below the target.

Polling the metric api server we can see the correct metric. 
[image]

We can see the metric in prometheus over time where value never gets above 25% but scaling of the container still happens from 1-4. 
[image]

We can see where the pod has a target value of 100 but has shown history of scaling from 1 to 4. 
[image]

And the config for rule in prometheus adapter. 
[image]

Pod Helm Config
[image]

Any help or direction to check next would be great. The expected result is we should not see any autoscaling as the target, 100, is always greater then the metric.

---

UPDATE 1: Ran on watch and got this 
[image]

with this coming from prometheus -v 8 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Running Kube v1.11.8

Comment: Can you check if the hpa actually reports target as > 100 when the rescale happens? You could watch for `kubectl get hpa -w` output f.i.

Comment: You can also check prometheus adapter logs (make sure verbosity is at least `--v=6`). Look for the request made by the HPA and the actual prometheus query it results in. This query might or might not be different from what you're querying in your grafana screenshot.

Comment: @shkaper See updated post.

Comment: **(1.)** Can you check that when the HPA scaling events happen (below target/above target), the metric is really below/above 100 (query from Custom Metrics API with `kubectl get --raw="..."`)?
**(2.)** Can you manually trigger the metric to go up and down to observe the reaction of the HPA in detail?
**(3.)** What does the metric mean? Why is it associated with a Namespace object? What component produces the metric?